# can't open file which download with php code

Tags: php

```
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 readfile($file);
```

i downloaded file but can't open file ? why ?

Comment: Just for context for anyone answering this: the code sample the questioner has quoted is from the documentation on php.net for the [readfile](http://uk2.php.net/readfile) function

Comment: Can't open file in what... on your local machine?

Comment: use localhost
open this file in webroot of localhost , it open ,
when i download and open this file but can't

Comment: Does the following sound like your problem : you download a PDF using IE6 with this script and when you try to open it (using the option in the prompt when downloading) you get an error message stating that the file is corrupted? Especially the browser used (and to a lesser extent the type of files you open) could be important.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code (untested):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
@ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Comment: Isn't one of the things output buffering accomplishes allowing headers to go through before any content?

Comment: @Arda Xi is correct, ob_clean does not impact headers.

Comment: I stand corrected (that's why I said "I think" rather than making a definite assertion). Thanks for the pick-up on that guys - I learn something new every day.